# On-demand resources not downloading from testflight

Tags: on-demand-resources

I have enabled OnDemandResources and checked the flow in the simulator. It's working fine. When made a test flight release, I'm able to see the ODR field enabled and 1 asset file is available. But when installed, the resources are not getting downloaded.

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and changed build setting to legacy mode but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem I was facing.

"An asset pack is eligible for purging when all of the associated tags are no longer retained by any request. The resources associated with a tag may remain on the device for some time before it is purged, including across app launches."

Ultimately, the cache will get automatically purged if there is a memory issue, so it is only a cosmetic issue where users will potentially see your app as being larger than they expected, and then at some point down the line, it will be magically smaller.

So I copied my resources into another directory locally.

Another idea is I zipped my images and added zip file as on-demand resources. So after ODR got installed I extracted and copied my zip files contents locally. (I did this because finding the path for images in asset file was difficult in my case)